# Handling Memory Issues in a React Slideshow: How to Clear Cache or Optimize Data Fetching

Tags: reactjs, caching, memory

I'm currently facing an issue with a React-based website that presents a slideshow by fetching data from a server every 10 seconds. The continuous data fetching seems to be causing memory-related crashes after a few hours of runtime. I'm wondering if there's a way in React to efficiently clear cache or optimize the data fetching process to prevent these crashes.

I know websites by default cache and I've also already optimized the image size. However, even with these optimizations, because this site must always be running on a screen, the memory builds up.

Any insights or recommendations on how to handle memory issues in this context would be greatly appreciated.